# Equal/minus sign without a colon in a parameter expasion in bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables, variable-expansion

I found a snippet like this in a Bash script recently:

```
$ echo ${A=3}
```

Now, I know that `${A:=3}` would set the variable `A` if `A` is "falsy", or `${A:-3}` would return 3 if `A` is "falsy." I have never seen these similar expressions without the colon though, and I cannot find the explanation for these colon-less expressions in the [Bash's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

What is going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the documentation does explain what is going on here, [even if burying the lede a bit](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> When not performing substring expansion, using the form described below (e.g., ‘:-’), Bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null. ***Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.*** Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests for both parameters’ existence and that its value is not null; if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence.

In practice, this means that they behave the same way if the variables are unset:

```
$ echo ${A=no-colon}
no-colon
$ echo ${B:=with-colon}
with-colon
$ echo $A
no-colon
$ echo $B
with-colon
```

However, if the variables are set to the empty string, then the behavior is different. The expression with a colon will set the variable and return the value, and the one without will leave the variable as is (i.e., set to the empty string) and return its empty value:

```
$ A='' ; B=''
$ echo ${A=no-colon}

$ echo ${B:=with-colon}
with-colon
$ echo $A

$ echo $B
with-colon
```

As stated in the documentation, the same behavior applies to the other "operators" (`-`, `?`, `+`).

*Posting it in the spirit of [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and because it took a surprisingly long time for me to learn it, even after finding it in code. Maybe making it a bit more explicit, with some examples, can help somebody else out there :)*